# How to customize PagesAPIViewsets that it can retrieve data in "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/pages/?slug=home-page&locale=en" endpoint in wagtail?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-apiv2

By default wagtail.api.v2 retrieves data by id. but i want to modify that it can retrieve data by slug+locale parameters

so, i decided to create endpoint "api/v2/pages/?slug=slug"

but when i am sending request into this endpoint, it returns me a single filter response page such as below

{
"meta": {
"total_count": 1
},
"items": [
{
"id": 34,
"meta": {
"type": "blog.BlogPage",
"detail_url": "http://apimabas.demodev.click/api/v2/pages/34/",
"html_url": "http://apimabas.demodev.click/en/blogs/test/",
"slug": "test",
"first_published_at": "2023-03-31T06:11:02.402366Z",
"locale": "en"
},
"title": "Comparison"
}
]
}

my serializer and view had been given below

```
type hereclass CustomPageSerializer(PageSerializer):
    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        fields['detail_url'] = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        return fields
    
    def get_detail_url(self, obj):
    
        return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri(obj.slug + '/')


class CustomPageViewSet(PagesAPIViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    model = Page
    base_serializer_class = CustomPageSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        # Retrieve the object using the custom slug field

        slug = self.kwargs[self.lookup_field]
        try:
            obj = Page.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
        except Page.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound

        # Return the object
        return obj.specific
    

    def detail_view(self, request):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @classmethod
    def get_urlpatterns(cls):
        """
        This returns a list of URL patterns for the endpoint
        """
        return [
            path("", cls.as_view({"get": "listing_view"}), name="listing"),
            path("<slug:slug>/", cls.as_view({"get": "detail_view"}), name="detail"),
            path("find/", cls.as_view({"get": "find_view"}), name="find"),
        ]
```

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow. What did you expect your new endpoint to return?

Comment: by default wagtail.api.v2 retrieves data for such syntaxys endpoint 'api/v2/pages/id'
i want to create custom method that can retrieve data by sending request into such enpoints 'api/v2/pages/slug/locale

Comment: I think changing the lookup field to 'slug' will give you responses for `api/v2/pages/slug/` But I am a little surprised that the detail_url in your output has an id rather than a slug. I think you may have to customize the serializer to make that return urls of the form you want. Are you sure you can't live with urls like /api/v2/pages/?slug=about&locale=en instead of /api/v2/pages/about/en/?

Comment: i changed my get_detail_url method, it was not generating correct url.  /api/v2/pages/?slug=about&locale=en instead this endpoint is an filter endpoint, so it returns a filter result response, but i need a detail page of each object, so i had to create custom method. in wagtail id is changing after deleting process and slug is changeable also. maybe i will create a custom second slug field into core page models, to create retrieve method in another projects